# Parsing multiple log files with python script - How to?

Tags: python, command-line, matomo

Im using a python script to import log files in to Piwik and **I can successfully parse one log file at a time**, but how do I do it for all of the log files in a directory?

From the readme the usage of the script is:

```
import_logs.py [options] log_file [ log_file [...] ]
```

So if I had log files u_ex120101.log to u_ex120701.log how could I run it once to do all of those files? I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but I know basically nothing about python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about just calling the script with a shell wildcard?

```
cd logs/
import_logs.py u_*.log
```

*Note: This does not work for windows though. Windows shell will not expand the wildcard. The receiving program must do it (i.e., import_logs.py)

**Solution for windows:** Use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) or another *nix-like shell replacement.

Comment: I should probably add I'm using windows cmd.exe for this. Will that work there?

Comment: @acowley: Did you try it? Windows uses the `*` wildcard as well.

Comment: Yeah I did. I think it's trying to parse the import_logs.py file too

Comment: Sorry, I had it wrong. Using it like this C:\xampp\htdocs\piwik\misc\log-analytics>python import_logs.py --idsite=1 --url=http://localhost/piwik/ u_*.log it doesnt work. It sayes u_*.log file not found. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Nevermind. Windows shell sucks and doesn't expand your wildcards like *nix. The receiving program is responsible for expanding the raw arg

Comment: thanks anyway. agreed it sucks. cant change that at work though unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of logfiles in a directory and you only want a range of them, another option is to write a small Python script that takes in a range and a base, and just calls import logs for each one (or, if you want to get particularly fancy, you could actually import `import_logs` directly).

You can run any shell command with `Popen` in Python.  So if you wanted to run `import_logs log_base_str01123.txt`, you could just run the following:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
print Popen("import_logs.py log_base_str01123.txt", stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

and if you wanted to do that for a bunch of strings:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os
base_prefix = "u_ex"
base_suffix = ".log"
logs=["my", "list", "of", "log#s"]
for log in logs:
    path = "import_logs.py {prefix}{log_name}{suffix}".format(
                prefix=prefix, log_name=log, suffix=base_suffix)
    if not os.path.exists(log):
        print Popen(,
                stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read())
```

This could be a more general purpose solution/let you have more finegrained control.

If you want to go through a list of consecutive values, you can just use:

```
logs = map(str, range(start_number, end_number + 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is out of my league right now. I've just generated a list of all the file names and added them to the script seperated by a space. Ugly but working.

Comment: @acowley understandable.  Frankly though, that's probably the easiest way to do it if you don't have a lot of programming experience and you don't need to do this often.  You could get fancier and adapt the script to make logs = all the logs modified in the past week.

Comment: the [ log_file [...] ] part of the usage example doesn't indicate another way of adding multiple logs? I don't understand what that means. Thanks again.

Comment: @acowley , you could use either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module in Python.
The glob.glob() function takes in a string containing wildcard and returns a list with matching files and folders.

Example:

```
import blob

# assume file_argument is a variable containing wildcard
file_argument = '/var/log/*.log'

for log_file in glob.glob(file_argument):
    do_stuff(log_file)
```

This will cause Python to perform the wildcard expansion for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows Server 2012, I have no experience with Python, and I have 4 years' worth of log files each about 20mb-40mb in size.

I just wanted to share that I used a free utility that I found called Merge Logs to solve this problem. Using `copy *.log merged.txt` or `type *.log > merged.txt` took a **very very** long time, whereas this utility did the job I need in a few minutes.

Here's the download: http://www.allscoop.com/dotnet-software/log-file-merge.php

Comment: Thanks @philwilks, that looks like a handy tool.